# How can I join two dataframes on a key with List[f64] dtype

Tags: python-polars

I have the following two dataframes, and I would like to join them on a key that is a `List[pl.Float64]` dtype. Is there any way I can achieve the following desired result?

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2.0], "coords": [(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0)]})
df_allowed = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "coords": [(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)],
        "people": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    }
)
df.join(df_allowed, how="left", on="coords")

df_expected = pl.DataFrame(
    {"id": [1.0, 2.0], "coords": [(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0)], "people": ["Alice", "Bob"]}
)
```

The real dataframe has a length in the 10_000s, and the coords represent geographical coordinates that will be used downstream.

Comment: Having read these wonderful answers, I thought I could be smart and modify my own join to join on `[pl.col(coords).arr.first(), pl.col(coords).arr.last()]`. I've raised an issue here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `struct`ify and `unnest` the `coords` columns to do the joins, can transform it back later if desired or leave it as separate columns:

```py
def unnest_coords(df):
    return df.with_columns(pl.col('coords').arr.to_struct(fields=['x', 'y'])).unnest('coords')

def nest_coords(df):
    return df.select(pl.exclude('x', 'y'), pl.concat_list('x', 'y').alias('coords'))

nest_coords(unnest_coords(df).join(unnest_coords(allowed), how='left', on=['x', 'y']))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬────────────┐
│ id  ┆ people ┆ coords     │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ f64 ┆ str    ┆ list[f64]  │
╞═════╪════════╪════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ Alice  ┆ [1.0, 2.0] │
│ 2.0 ┆ Bob    ┆ [3.0, 4.0] │
└─────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is small and efficiency isn't important then you could do a cross-join followed by a filter for when the coords are equal like this

```
df.join(df_allowed,
       how='cross') \
  .filter(pl.col('coords')==pl.col('coords_right')) \
  .drop('coords_right')
```

Alternatively, if the data is big so that efficiency *is* important then, if your list columns are always two elements long, you could make new columns and join by those like this

```
def coords_split(df):
    return df.with_columns(x=pl.col('coords').arr.first(), y=pl.col('coords').arr.last())

coords_split(df) \
    .join(
        coords_split(df_allowed),
        how='left', on=['x','y']
        ) \
    .drop(['x','y','coords_right'])
```

Answer (score 1):

diagonal concat + `.groupby`

```
(pl.concat([df, df_allowed], how="diagonal")
   .groupby("coords", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.col("id").drop_nulls().first(), 
      pl.col("people").drop_nulls()
   )
   .explode("people")
   .drop_nulls()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬─────┬────────┐
│ coords     ┆ id  ┆ people │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ list[f64]  ┆ f64 ┆ str    │
╞════════════╪═════╪════════╡
│ [1.0, 2.0] ┆ 1.0 ┆ Alice  │
│ [3.0, 4.0] ┆ 2.0 ┆ Bob    │
└────────────┴─────┴────────┘
```